# Unable to Create Instances for multiple Users in my FastAPI HF spaces Application with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, huggingface

I am deploying a FastAPI application in the Hugging Face Spaces environment, and I'm encountering an issue where it only allows one instance for all users sharing the same space. Despite attempts to handle user-specific configurations within the Docker image and entrypoint.sh script, the current setup doesn't dynamically create separate instances for individual users entering the space. Seeking guidance on modifying the Dockerfile or entrypoint.sh to allow multiple users to have distinct instances of the FastAPI application within the Hugging Face Spaces environment

```
# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Define the user ID in the environment variable USER_ID with a default value
ARG USER_ID=1000
ENV USER_ID=$USER_ID

# Check if the user already exists
RUN if [ -z "$USER_ID" ]; then \
      echo "User ID not provided. Using the default user ID 1000."; \
      USER_ID=1000; \
    fi && \
    if id "$USER_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
      echo "User with ID $USER_ID already exists."; \
    else \
      adduser --uid "$USER_ID" --disabled-password --gecos '' appuser; \
    fi

# Set appropriate permissions for the application directory
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app && chmod -R 755 /app

# Install gosu (adjust the package manager based on your base image)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gosu && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the entrypoint script as executable
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Switch to the user for improved security
USER appuser

# Define the entrypoint script to handle user creation and application startup
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

# Default command to run if the user doesn't provide a command
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "7860", "--reload"]
```

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Set permissions at runtime
chmod -R 777 /app

# Execute the main command
exec "$@"
```

I've explored several strategies to enable multiple instances for users within the Hugging Face Spaces environment. One approach involved handling the majority of user setup logic within the entrypoint.sh script, and I've also experimented with different configurations in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Do you know a specific data directory that needs to be written?  Are you trying to have multiple (possibly remote) users using the same container, or allow multiple (local) users to launch the container themselves (with separate instances per user)?

Comment: My generic advice here would be to not accept a specific uid as part of the image build, don't `chmod 0777` anything ever, but do start the container with a `docker run -u` option naming the numeric host user ID and a `docker run -v` option mounting host storage into the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think to set up my hugging face space for multiple users to be able to use the image I am using in the space but have their own instance here is the link I set it to public  if you can help please do this is very confusing  https://huggingface.co/spaces/circulartext/Thespeedreadapp